# How to include SCSS file in HTML

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I dont know how to include SCSS file in my website but I have completely developed .scss file using notepad. Please let me know how to include it in my website?

Comment: Please read the FAQ and learn How to post questions. Thanks

Comment: What wrong in my question?? Normally .css files are linked to HTML files through <link>tag, like wise please let me know how to include SASS files. Do i need to convert SCSS file into CSS file??

Comment: Well that's kinda the point of a CSS Preprocessor:  to create CSS files.  Have you ever heard of a browser that supports Sass?

Comment: Yes, yo need to compile sass/scss files to css first. Thats why it is called "precompose".

Comment: You can compile easily using this [solution](https://thecoderain.blogspot.com/2019/12/run-and-compile-sass-scss-file-to-css.html)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can't have a link to SCSS File in your HTML page.You have to compile it down to CSS First. No there are lots of video tutorials you might want to check out.
Lynda provides great video tutorials on SASS.
there are also free screencasts you can google...

For official documentation visit this site
http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html
And why have you chosen notepad to write Sass??
you can easily download some free text editors for better code handling.